# Send data in MD5 format

Tags: md5, jmeter

In my project  there is a scenario that

user will log in  -> browse some pages -> then he will click on the logout link .

to test this scenario  in JMeter, I used CSV config so that I can test this scenario for 50 users.  during logout, each user unique userid is sent as request in the MD5 format.

How can I sent the userid in MD5 format in JMeter?

Comment: wait wait, you want to "mock" the service response? I'm confused can you re-phrase? or am I getting it right?

Comment: what i want to mean is , under thread group i add a common csv config element ,that csv contains the user details .

Comment: aha good. and what do you want to do with those details?

Comment: what i want to mean is , under thread group i add a common csv config element ,that csv contains the user details . now i add a simple controller under thread group , i gave the controller name " login" . now under the controller login there is the http request for login.in that http request parameter i sent the username and passoword dynamically using variable[ ${username} ,&{password}. now in the logout section http request , userid of each user is sent in the md5 format. so what i want to know that how can i sent the userid in md5 format during logout.  h

Comment: here i want to mention one point that in the user csv there was also a column userid , so can i use that field here.

Comment: ant is it clear now , or you need some more information , if required please tell me , i will provide .

Comment: sorry wasn't here, you've got great answer both of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use custom [MD5 function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#MD5supfont-color-gray-size-1-since-0-4-2-font-sup) from [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) set.
This will look like `${__MD5(${username})}`.

[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/jmeter-plugins/browse_thread/thread/628ae248a082b5a8) is also demo-script from plugin's author available, attached to conversation.

Comment: i have tried the function ${__MD5(${username})} but it is not sending the userid in the md5 format properly and also the same userid is showing for all the users.

Comment: I've tried both original demo-script as well as modified one - the same but ${__MD5(${username})} is sent as param along with HTTP Request, not Dummy Sampler - works fine for me (Jmeter 2.7 + JmeterPLugins 0.5.3).Possibly something with your script... Try to look into jmeter.log for details.

Comment: hi alies yes it is working correctly now . i havent installed jmeterplugins0.5.3 thats why it was not working previously , but after installation it is working correctly. thank you very much for the help  . can you give me your any chat id or email add ,i need to clear 2 -3 things but here i am not able to post with screenshot ,that why i will talk with you over there. may be some very basic problem but i have not able to found solutions for those and stuck in the same point for prity long time.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the dynamic user/session ID using a regex, then calculate the MD5 using BeanShell preprocessor. Some sample code is available [here](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/MD5-conversion-of-a-string-td531123.html) and [there](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Need-helping-creating-a-md5-hash-td3273251.html).

Comment: i have tried the function ${__MD5(${username})} but it is not sending the userid in the md5 format properly and also the same userid is showing for all the users.

Comment: You need to add a BeanShell preprocessor into your script, implement the script for MD5 string processing and use it with your variables.

Comment: Hi alexander , i have no knowledge in  BeanShell preprocessor and programming , can you please provide any link from where i can learn this programming and how to use the processor in jmeter from the beginner point of view.  will  it also solve the problem related to jeson response  where 2 subrequest of the parent request are par-allay running and in the view result tree in the response tab the response which is showing is not we are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Actually MD5 function was removed, use [__digest](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) with MD5 as first parameter instead:

> ```
> ${__digest(MD5,Errare humanum est,,,)}
> ```
>
> returns c49f00b92667a35c63708933384dad52